# In a bash shell, redirect standard error to standard output and reference the error part with a string prefix

Tags: bash, shell, output-redirect

The command `od / /dev/null` returns both standard error and standard output and is used here just for test.

I can redirect the standard error to standard output with:

```
echo "The command result is: $(od / /dev/null 2>&1)"
```

Which returns:

```
The command result is: od: /: read error: Is a directory
0000000
```

Whereas the error part is "od: /: read error: Is a directory" and the non error one is "0000000".

I need to add a reference in the output to distinguish which part is the standard error, by adding a prefix "The error is:", and get and output like:

```
The command result is: 0000000
The error is: od: /: read error: Is a directory
```

If there is no error, the string "The error is:" can still be part of the output.

Any advise how to accomplish this?

**EDIT:**

The [answer from *choroba*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62653533/6136214) works for the test command `od / /dev/null`, but when I try to use the following ssh command (which is what I'll actually use), the standard error goes at the end of the output instead of within the START/END strings and the START string is missing:

```
Command: echo "START___$(ssh user@1.1.1.900 2>&1 2> >(sed 's/^/ERR: /' >&2))___END"
Output: ___END__ERR: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 1.1.1.900: Name or service not known
```

When I use the test command with the addition of START/END strings, I get a normal output whereas the standard output and error is within START/END strings:

```
Command:echo "START___$(od / /dev/null 2>&1 2> >(sed 's/^/ERR: /' >&2))___END"
Output: START___0000000
ERR: od: /: read error: Is a directory___END
```

Any help for this scenario?

**EDIT 2**

I added the ssh command in a subprocess but still have the problem. Interestingly, it works OK for telnet.

SSH:

```
Command: echo "START___$((ssh user@1.1.1.900) 2>&1 2> >(sed 's/^/ERR: /' >&2))___END"

Output: ___END__ERR: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 1.1.1.900: Name or service not known
```

Telnet:

```
Command: echo "START___$((telnet 1.1.1.900) 2>&1 2> >(sed 's/^/ERR: /' >&2))___END"

Output: START___ERR: telnet: could not resolve 1.1.1.900/telnet: Name or service not known___END
```

**EDIT 3 - SOLUTION**

The solution to work with ssh command is to filter control chars from the ssh response before feeding sed:

```
echo "START___$(ssh user@1.1.1.900 2>&1 2> >(tr -d '[:cntrl:]' | sed 's/^/ERR: /' >&2))___END"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed and the process substitution:

```
echo "The command result is: $(od / /dev/null 2>&1 2> >(sed 's/^/ERR: /' >&2))"
```

Comment: Thanks! When I try to use your solution for the ssh program I get result as in my edited question. Do you have a solution for that one too?

Comment: Don't run the redirections on the target machine.

Comment: Example please. I need the entire ssh result (standard output + prefixed standard error) returned within START/END strings.

Comment: The solution to work with ssh command is to filter control chars from the ssh response before feeding sed: echo "START___$(ssh user@1.1.1.900 2>&1 2> >(tr -d '[:cntrl:]' | sed 's/^/ERR: /' >&2))___END"

Comment: You can also replace \x0d without the following \x0a by a newline: `perl -pe 's/\xd(?!\xa)/\n/g`

Answer (score 0):

For Debian based Linuxes, run `apt install devscripts`, and then try the  [**`annotate-output`**](https://linux.die.net/man/1/annotate-output) util.

```
annotate-output od / /dev/null
```

Output:

```
07:21:44 I: Started od / /dev/null
07:21:44 E: od: /: read error: Is a directory
07:21:44 O: 0000000
07:21:44 I: Finished with exitcode 1
```